# JQuery not woking

Tags: jquery

My JQuery does not fire up the sanitize function.I need to take the value from the input field name , sanitize it (with santize function) and display it in path input field. Why isn't it working ? I use PHP 5.3 and HEIDISQL

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <?php 

    include('conect.php');
    if(($_POST)&&(!empty($_POST['name']))&&(!empty($_POST['path'])) ){
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $path=$_POST['path'];

    function sanitize($title) {
        $title = strip_tags($title);
        // Preserve escaped octets.
        $title = preg_replace('|%([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])|', '---$1---', $title);
        // Remove percent signs that are not part of an octet.
        $title = str_replace('%', '', $title);
        // Restore octets.
        $title = preg_replace('|---([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])---|', '%$1', $title);

        if (seems_utf8($title)) {
            if (function_exists('mb_strtolower')) {
                $title = mb_strtolower($title, 'UTF-8');
            }
            $title = utf8_uri_encode($title, 200);
        }

        $title = strtolower($title);
        $title = preg_replace('/&.+?;/', '', $title); // kill entities
        $title = str_replace('.', '-', $title);
        $title = preg_replace('/[^%a-z0-9 _-]/', '', $title);
        $title = preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $title);
        $title = preg_replace('|-+|', '-', $title);
        $title = trim($title, '-');

        return $title;
    }   

    mysql_query("UPDATE menus SET name='$name' , path='$path'");
    }

    ?>
    <html>
    <head>

    <script>


$(document).ready(
function(){
          $("#name").change(function(){
             $("#path").sanitize("name").val();             

          });
} );


</script>

    </head>

    <body>
            <form action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>" method="post">
            <label for="nume">Name</label><input type="text" name="name" />
            <label for="cale">Path</label><input type="text" name="path" />
            <input type="submit" name="submit"/>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Your `sanitize()` function is written in PHP but is executing as Javascript. You will need to re-write it in Javascript if you want to use it on the client side. Otherwise you could use an ajax call to call on the PHP side.

Comment: could you give me an example for an ajax call if the ajax code is in the same page as the php code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't working because it is written in PHP and you are trying to run it client side as if it were JavaScript.

You can't trust the client to send you sanitised data — you don't control the client.

Answer (score 1):

Because the rest is PHP code, which you run as Javascript